# Is the class of models of Zermelo set theory that have a hierarchy elementary?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $\mathrm Z$ be original Zermelo set theory with the foundation scheme (aka ZF-Replacement). Let us say that a model $M$ of $\mathrm Z$ has a hierarchy if there is a $M$-definable sequence $\langle H_i\mid i\in\mathrm{Ord}^M\rangle$ that vaguely resembles the Von Neumann hierarchy in a model of ZF. More precisely it should satisfy (from the point of view of $M$):

1. All $H_i$ are transitive sets
2. $H_i\subseteq H_j$ for $i\leq j$
3. $M=\bigcup_{i\in\mathrm{Ord}^M} H_i$

The models of $\mathrm Z$ that come up in practice usually have a hierarchy as they often are limit points of a hierarchy of a larger model, this can, but need not come in the form of the Von Neumann hierarchy. For example $V_\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $H_\kappa$ if $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal, and also $L_\alpha[B]$ fits this bill if $B\in L_\alpha[B]\models\mathrm Z$. There are, however, many models of $\mathrm Z$ that do not have a hierarchy. Models of $\mathrm Z$ that have a hierarchy must satisfy some sentences that are not provable in $\mathrm Z$, for example the axiom $\mathrm{TC}$ of transitive containment (every set is a subset of a transitive set), and more.

My question is:

> Is the class of models of $\mathrm Z$ that have a hierarchy axiomatisable?

If anyone is interested, some notes with more information are available as [A transitive model of $\mathrm{ZC}+\neg\mathrm{TC}$](https://www.uni-muenster.de/IVV5WS/WebHop/user/alietz/notes/zermelo.pdf) on my website.

Comment: You should get in touch with Adam Epstein (from Warwick).

Comment: What do you mean by "foundation scheme"? $\in$-induction? Because stating that $\in$ is well-founded is not a scheme. It's a single axiom.

Comment: It is a piece of cake to show that the class of models of NBG that have a hierarchy is elementary . So the class of models of Z that have a hierarchy is pseudo-elementary, right?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will wait a few days in case somebody answers this question before I will reach out :) The foundation schemes means "any definable (w/ parameters) class $C$ has an element it is disjoint from", i.e. foundation for all classes. While this is equivalent to the foundation axiom in ZF, it is strictly stronger over just original Zermelo set theory (this is a result of Jensen-Schröder).

Comment: @OlivierRoche Could you explain what pseudo-elementary means? I am not familiar with that term. Also do you mean the second order version of Z instead of NBG? Models of NBG trivially have the Von Neumann hierarchy...

Comment: @AndreasLietz You'll find a definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_class). Anyway, the answer is no since a model of Z is not a reduct of a model of NBG. I had a wrong definition in mind...

Comment: In your definition, is the family $\langle H_i\mid i\in\mathrm{Ord}^M\rangle$ uniformly definable?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! To be precise, the class consisting of all ordered pairs $(i, H_i)$, $i\in\mathrm{Ord}^M$ should be definable over $M$.

Answer (score 1):

### One formula to rule them all?

Given a model $M$ of Z, we say that a formula $\varphi$ **witnesses that $M$ has a hierarchy** if it satisfies :

1. for $i \in \operatorname{Ord}(M)$, $\varphi(i, M)$ is transitive.
2. for $i \leqslant j \in \operatorname{Ord}(M)$, $\varphi(i,M) \subseteq \varphi(j, M)$.
3. for all $x \in M$, there is $i \in \operatorname{Ord}(M)$ such that $x \in \varphi(i, M)$.

We can speak of the  set $H$ of all formulas that witness that some model $M$ of Z has a hierarchy. Now, *assuming that having a hierarchy is elementary*, there are two possibilities :

- either there are finitely many $\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_n \in H$ such that for any model $M$ of Z with a hierarchy some $\varphi_i$ witnesses that $M$ has a hierarchy. Then the class of models of Z having a hierarchy is axiomatized by the formula stating "some $\varphi_i, 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$ witnesses that $M$ has a hierarchy".
- or we should be able to use compactness to get a model of "$M$ has a hierarchy but no formula of $H$ witnesses it", which would be a contradiction.

Hence, an axiomatization of "having a hierarchy" must boil down to a single formula of the said form.

Comment: this was to long to fit in a comment.